# Status Bar doesnot display when adding UIImagePickerController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to show a Camera view in between Navigation bar & Tab bar, so I added the `UIImagePickerController` object as follows.

```
picker = [[Camera3DViewController alloc] init];

picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

picker.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.view.transform, 1, 1);

[self.view addSubview:picker.view];

[picker viewWillAppear:YES];

[picker viewDidAppear:YES];
```

Note that `Camera3DViewController` is a subclass of `UIImagePickerController` Class.

Camera get display but status bar does not shown, so I use,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

but still it does not show the status bar.

Please guide me to solve the above problem.

Comment: You really shouldn't be subclassing UIImagePickerController. From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html: This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.

Comment: setStatusBarHidden:YES is supposed to hide the statusbar. You should send the setStatusBarHidden:NO message to show the statusbar.

Comment: Hi Robot, I have already check the result for without sub classing the UIImagePickerController but still its doesn't shows the status bar.

Comment: Hi All, I am not getting any solution for this. Is anybody facing the same problem.

Comment: yes I am facing the same problem.  Still no solution found.

Answer (score 3):

I subclassed UIImagePictureController and added:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

It is important to show status after [super viewDidAppear:animated]; call, else it didn't appear. Also it is important to call superclass method.